# Combining IF, ISTEXT and LEN functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My current formula:

```
=IF((LEN(J3))=4,J3,IF(J3="","",IF(ISTEXT(J3),"",J3)))
```

What I'm trying to achieve with this formula:

1. if any cell in column J istext then return as blank.
2. Shorten 68148101 to show as = 8148

Can't seem to get these two formulas to work together..

Comment: Or maybe I need to combine =IF(ISTEXT(C7),"",C7) and =VALUE(MID(C10,2,4))?? somehow

Comment: Do you have an actual visual representation of your sample input, requirements and desired output?

Comment: So Column J will have random inputs of numbers ranging from 4 digits to 6. or it will have a range of text. so if J2 has "pweo" A2 will output "blank"
however if J3 has "68148101" A2 will output "8148"

Comment: That's quite clear then, please see answer below. Does that do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on you requirements in your comment, try the following in `A2`:

```
=IF(J2="","",IF(ISTEXT(J2),"",IF(LEN(J2)>4,MID(J2,2,4),J2)))
```